# PHP Iterate over array and insert key/value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of employee data that I am working with that I convert to JSON and pass it to a plugin to create an org chart. The org chart has multiple levels and my goal is to color code those levels to show the different orgs.

My array is nested and has the `manager` and the `children`.

I am trying to figure out how I can loop over this array and assign a color for the different levels.

For example, the very first level of the array would be Blue, the next level would be red etc. All I need to do is add in a key for `class` and then its value which would be levelx (where x is the number of levels deep it is).

The end goal here is just to be able to figure out how to add the same key/value on all of the records on the same level.

Here is an example of the array with the `class key` in play.

Are there any PHP functions that can determine its level within a nested array that will make this easier?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [QID] => Q1234
            [MgrQID] => Array
                (
                )

            [NTID] => xxxxx
            [MgrNTID] => xxxx
            [title] => xxxx
            [MgrName] => xxxx
            [name] => Bob Jones
            [class] => level1
            [CountOfDirects] => 9
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [QID] => Q56789
                            [MgrQID] => 1234
                            [NTID] => xxxx
                            [MgrNTID] => xxxx
                            [title] => xxxx
                            [MgrName] => xxxx
                            [name] => Tim Cook
                            [class] => level2
                            [CountOfDirects] => 0
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [QID] => Q5678
                            [MgrQID] => Q1234
                            [NTID] => xxxxx
                            [MgrNTID] => xxxx
                            [title] => xxxx
                            [MgrName] => xxxx
                            [name] => Bob Tom
                            [class] => level2
                            [CountOfDirects] => 0
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )


                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [QID] => Q9999
                            [MgrQID] => Q1234
                            [NTID] => xxxx
                            [MgrNTID] => xxxx
                            [title] => xxxx
                            [MgrName] => xxxx
                            [name] => xxxx
                            [class] => level2
                            [CountOfDirects] => 0
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [QID] => Q6665
                            [MgrQID] => Q1234
                            [NTID] => xxxx
                            [MgrNTID] => xxxx
                            [title] => xxxx
                            [MgrName] => xxxx
                            [name] => xxxx
                            [class] => level2
                            [CountOfDirects] => 6
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [QID] => Q4322
                                            [MgrQID] => Q6665
                                            [NTID] => xxxx
                                            [MgrNTID] => xxxx
                                            [title] => xxxx
                                            [MgrName] => xxxx
                                            [name] => xxxx
                                            [class] => level3
                                            [CountOfDirects] => 0
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [QID] => Q3333
                                            [MgrQID] => Q6665
                                            [NTID] => xxxx
                                            [MgrNTID] => xxxx
                                            [title] => xxxx
                                            [MgrName] => xxxx
                                            [name] => xxxx
                                            [class] => level3
                                            [CountOfDirects] => 0
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )


                                )

                        )


                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Do you have a level limit?

Comment: @RayannNayran There are no limits in place. This could be 5 levels deep or 20 levels deep depending on how many employees fall under the person being viewed.

Comment: Have you tried anything to implement it?

Comment: I was able to traverse the arrary with a normal loop but I wasnt able to distinguish the level it was on. I had access to the seed in the loop but they were all different which gave me a different class for every record, not putting them into groups like i intended

Comment: Ok, put that in your question, so we can see that and help you better!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php  Take a look at this.  You can use array_push to put in levelx based on an iterative variable.  Post whatever code you come up with and if you get stuck, let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function to walk array recursively:

```
function setLevel(&$arr, $level)
{
    foreach ($arr as &$element) {
        $element['class'] = 'level-' . $level;
        setLevel($element['children'], $level + 1);
    }
}

setLevel($arr, 1);
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/OvyGLV).

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it's been helpful.